# What is the opposite of a grazing angle?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

A grazing angle is almost parallel to the surface.

Is there another word for an angle almost perpendicular to the surface?

(Or is that just it?)

Comment: Not about English as such but physics.

Comment: Would these terms work in this ELU question and answer? http://english.stackexchange.com/q/63429/18655

Comment: Well, I don't think "grazing hit" is a technical physics term. That's a common English expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [***oblique***](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oblique) : *Designating geometric lines or planes that are neither parallel nor perpendicular.*

So an "oblique hit" would be an impact with a higher angle of incidence than your "grazing hit" but would not be a true perpendicular hit.

Comment: This word fits. Although __oblique__ excludes the chance of perpendicularity, it fits in the context that I am using this word.

Answer (score 2):

Consider *near-normal*, where *[normal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/normal#Noun)* means “(geometry) A line or vector that is perpendicular to another line, surface, or plane”, and also consider *off-plumb*, where *[plumb](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plumb#Adjective)* means “truly vertical” or “(informal) Squarely, directly; completely”.

Comment: If you were talking about a technical discussion of geometry, I'd agree that "normal" is the correct word. But in day-to-day conversation, if you said, "That was a normal hit!" I don't think people would interpret this in the geometric sense. "Normal" is the opposite of "tangent" in this sense, not of "grazing". "Plumb on" is occassionally used to mean a straight-in hit, I'd endorse "plumb" or variations.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, maybe "direct hit"? "Straight in?"

Comment: "Head-on" might be a good possibility too.