# Is there a word for "sticking up at an angle"?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's the word *perpendicular* when sticking straight up, but is there a word for "sticking up at an angle"? I mean, it's not particularly hard to just say "sticking up at an angle" but I wondered about this when someone just described something as "perpendicular-ish"; the exact context was an instruction about installing a sign upright but sloped backwards, *not* exactly at 90 degrees.

Comment: [***Protruding***](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/protrude), or similar? What is your *exact* intended context?

Comment: Projecting at about N degrees.

Comment: "Bent"?  "Angled"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers edited

Comment: related - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79023/what-is-the-opposite-of-a-grazing-angle

Comment: It would be a *slight slant*. The only word I find that actually means *nearly perpendicular* is *sheer*, but it better applies to a surface, especially a cliff or rock face.

Comment: *Slanting* or *angled*.

Comment: jhocking: Closevote (for lack of detailed context) retracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **oblique** or **obliquely**
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/oblique

> The nail was set obliquely in the wood.

Comment: This answer works great, I'll just wait a day before accepting it.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably say "install the sign so that it is angled backwards by 2 degrees," but a term used for engineering is *cant* (noun, singular) which is a slope or tilt.

Random image:

[image]

Comment: I cannot say this word without thinking of Thieves' Cant :D

Comment: **verb: 1** Have or cause to have a slanting or oblique position; tilt.
*with object* ‘he canted his head to look at the screen’
*no object* ‘mismatched slate roofs canted at all angles’ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cant

Comment: Not just engineering.